# Getting Cross-site scripting (XSS) coverity issue as passing string input in java controller method

Tags: java, request, coverity

@POST
public Response method1(@QueryParam String input){
...
}

Here input is normal string and not html content.
As I am processing input directly, getting coverity issue -
tainted_source: Entering this function as a framework entry point. Parameter input is tainted because it comes from an HTTP request.

How to sanitize input to avoid this issue?

Comment: The `tainted_source` event is just one element of the finding.  In the Coverity GUI you should be able to access and review the entire event tree.  Add more of the events to your question, and the associated code.  In particular, there should be an event that shows the tainted data being used in an unsafe way.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak I have mentioned the starting point of the event tree. It is one of the method inside controller which receives String input from http request (It is POST call) . What should I be doing to sanitize it so that tainted data is not propagated in the code?

Comment: Sanitization always depends on how the data is *used*, so I would need to see what the sink is.  It is not possible to block the tainted data from entering the program; instead you have to remember that it is tainted and handle it safely every time it is used.